# Lualatex with latexing

Tags: sublime-text

What Latexing file I have to modify and I can compile with LuaLatex by default?
I only view build arguments but not how to modify from pdflatex to lualatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a `.latexmkrc` file in the same directory as the TeX source, with the following contents:

```
$pdflatex = 'lualatex %O %S';
$pdf_mode = 1;
$postscript_mode = $dvi_mode = 0;
```

This tells LaTeXMK to use lualatex, without having to worry about changing settings in Sublime Text.

Comment: and how can I execute it? It doesn't work with CTRL+b

Comment: Can you press `ctrl+l, ctrl+b`, then choose "Build With: LaTeX"?